# Error message, subscript out of range in vb6

Tags: vb6

I hava a program that monitor a folder name it prog1 and a program that will render the file in database name it prog2. Everytime that a new file is being drag and drop to the monitored folder prog1 will get the filename and pass it to prog2 to render. There is no problem regarding drag/drop no matter how many files you drag/drop to a monitored folder. My problem is there is a pop up error when i try to copy and paste 5 files and above to a monitored folder saying that subscript out of range. Is theres a difference between drag/drop vs copy/paste regarding the time when its actually being copied to a monitored folder? Thanks for anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I'm only guessing here....

You have to make prog2 an array. You can't pass more than 1 string in the same variable without an array.